# Форма не отправляет сообщения

Tags: php, html

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
     $("#main-form").submit(function() {

      $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "../../form.php",
       data:$(this).serialize(),
       success: function() {
        alert('Ваша заявка отправлена!')
       }
      });

        // event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
    });
```

```html
<form id="main-form" method="POST">
        <p>Выберите удобный способ связи, мы перезвоним либо напишем и вы сможете задать все интересующие вас вопросы. Так-же произведем рассчет стоимости вашего будущего видео-ролика</p>

        <div class="radio__container">
          <label>
            <input type="radio" name="messenger" value="email" checked>
            <span><img src="assets/img/links/1.png"></span>
        </label>

        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="messenger" value="email" checked>
          <span><img src="assets/img/links/2.png"></span>
      </label>

      <label>
          <input type="radio" name="messenger" value="email" checked>
          <span><img src="assets/img/links/viber.png"></span>
      </label>

      <label>
          <input type="radio" name="messenger" value="email" checked>
          <span><img src="assets/img/links/3.png"></span>
      </label>


      <label>
          <input type="radio" name="messenger" value="email" checked>
          <span><img src="assets/img/links/4.png"></span>
      </label>

      <label>
          <input type="radio" name="messenger" value="email" checked>
          <span><img src="assets/img/links/5.png"></span>
      </label>

      <label>
          <input type="radio" name="messenger" value="email" checked>
          <span><img src="assets/img/links/6.png"></span>
      </label>

    </div>

    <input type="text" required placeholder="Укажите ваш мобильный" name="phone" id="phone">

    <input type="text" required placeholder="Укажите ваше имя" name="name" id="name">

    <input type="submit" value="Запросить звонок" id="submit">
    </form>
```

```
    <?php


$adminemail="leoteam53@yandex.ru";  // e-mail админа
$backurl1="http://pasha/";
// Принимаем данные с формы

$name=$_POST['name'];
$phone=$_POST['phone'];
$messenger=$_POST['messenger'];

$msg="name:". $name . "
phone:" . $phone . "
messenger:" . $messenger . "";

mail("$adminemail", "Сообщение от $name", "$msg");

exit;
```

Comment: У тебя параметры функции mail() должны передаваться как параметры, а не как строка. Что пишет сервер? И зачем ты принтуешь, если используешь ajax ?(return). Exit - это функция, тебе она здесь вообще не зачем.

Comment: $(this).serialize() может ссылаться на область видимости функции, а не формы.

Comment: `$("#main-form").submit(function() {` - ты должен принять event и отменить его: `$("#main-form").submit(function(enevt) { event.preventDefault();`. Зачем используешь `url: "../../form.php",` ? Сложный твой вопрос, хотя бы ошибки для примера дал или описал проблему.

Comment: Консоль никакой ошибки не выдает. Alert выводится,но сообщение не приходит.